# Use $_POST after submit form

Tags: 8, forms

I create a form and a page with controller in Drupal 8.

I want print value of my example input after submit form.

For example my input name is "Tel_number".

My code in controller page is:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class MymoduleController extends ControllerBase {
    public function mymodule() {
      $form['test'] = array (
         '#markup' => \Drupal::request()->request->get('Tel_number'),
      );
    return $form;
    }
}
?>
```

But no resault print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code in form submit:

```
$_SESSION['Tel_number'] = $form_state->getValue('Tel_number');
```

And use this code in controller:

```
$TelNumber = array(
   '#markup' => $_SESSION['Tel_number'],
);
return $TelNumber ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your controller is in a new request. If you stored the data in the database retrieve it from there. If you did not store the data in submit in some place it is no longer available. You could use a session variable or a url query parameter to transfer the data from the form submit to the controller:

```
public function myFormSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  ...
  $form_state->setRedirect('route_to_controller', [], ['query' => [
    'Tel_number' => '123456789',
  ]]);
}
```

and the controller

```
public function showNumber(Request $request) {

  $build['test'] = ['#markup' => $request->query->get('Tel_number')];

  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Tnx . How can I use 'Tel_number' value not fix number? And how can I print this 'Tel_number' in my controller page ?

Comment: This is only an example, of course you would put there the user input. The code from your question should work to print the data in the controller. The variable should normally be `$build`, the name you choose is a bit misleading, but it works nevertheless.

Comment: I edit my code before your answer. and this code was not work for me :(

Comment: You would need to use `\Drupal::request()->query->get()`, but better pull the request from the route as function parameter. I add an example.

Comment: This is GET method . I want use POST method

Comment: Don't know how that is possible. Are you sure you want a redirect to a controller. Or do you want a rebuild of the form?

Comment: Tnx.I use getvalue and worked for me

Comment: @SiMoNe You say you found a solution `getvalue` please share your solution, thanks.